# Get differences between two folders and copy results to third folder

Tags: files

I basically want to do what the title says. I've looked up this question several different ways, but no previous answer seems to work for me. I'm hoping for a command-line way to do this, preferably one command only. I've looked into using diff and rsync, but both compare folders when I just want to compare contents. I also have no idea on how to translate the output of diff into a command that moves the output.

My setup has two folders; one with nested folders containing mp3 files and one with just mp3 files. It looks like this:

- Folder A

  - random folder

    - thing A
    - thing B
  - random folder 2

    - thing C
- Folder B

  - thing A
  - thing C
  - thing D

I want the output to be:

- Folder C

  - thing B
  - thing D

Thanks so much, I'm just making my transition to using the Unix command line, I'm sorry if certain parts don't make sense!

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm using zsh.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff -qr folder1 folder2 > folder3
```

r -> is to read the sub directory

Comment: This would create a text file, not a directory with the files that are unique in either directory.